# PostgreSQL - How to ignore gross errors when using AVG() and MAX()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I have data in a table and I'd like to deliberately ignore some of the obviously incorrect data and take an average of the more plausible data.

Here's a simplified example of what I mean. Let's say I have a table that lists people and their height in cms.

I might use this to get the average height.....

```
SELECT AVG(height) FROM people;
```

That's fine if the data was all added correctly, but if they're (say) ten people in the database with correct heights, and one person who's height has been recorded as a billion centimeters tall then the AVG() won't return a sensible value - a classic example of GIGO (garbage in, garbage out)

Is there any way to adjust the above SQL function to ignore the outlying data points? - the data that is *so* different from all the rest it's got to be wrong?

I'm pretty sure the solution will involve one of the functions listed [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) but I'm having trouble finding some plain-english explanations of what they do and how they work.

UPDATE.......
My quoted example using height was selected for simplicity of explanation. Any proposed solution CAN'T simply filter between sensible values (i.e. height above 1.5m and below 2m) because for the actual data I'm using I don't know what the sensible values are! The solution needs to reject data that is massively different from the majority of the other data - so I guess that's where a knowledge of stats comes in handy.

Update 2) Sorry, going to have un-accept the answer I previously accepted (helpful though it was!). The standard deviation gives a value for the 'spread' of the data, but doesn't give any idea of where the outlying data is (i.e. stupidly tall people, or stupidly short people), so a clause like this...

```
WHERE height BETWEEN (SELECT a-2*sd FROM cte) AND (SELECT a+2*sd FROM cte);
```

Doesn't just remove the one stupidly tall person from one end of the range, it also removes all of the 'normal height' people from the other end of the range!
I can adjust the WHERE clause like this....

```
WHERE height BETWEEN (SELECT a-(sd/100) FROM cte) AND (SELECT a+(sd/100) FROM cte);
```

But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require individual tweaking for each different set of data

Answer (score 3):

You could use `FILTER`:

```
SELECT AVG(height) FILTER (WHERE height BETWEEN x AND y) AS avg_height
FROM people;

-- or `WHERE`:
SELECT AVG(height) AS avg_height
FROM people
WHERE height BETWEEN x AND y;
```

`x` and `y` are plausible values.

---

Alternatively you could filter out values that are outside range [`average() +/- 2*stddev()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_deviation_diagram_micro.svg)

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT AVG(height) a, STDDEV(height) sd
  FROM people
)
SELECT AVG(height)
FROM people
WHERE height BETWEEN (SELECT a-2*sd FROM cte) AND (SELECT a+2*sd FROM cte);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f515641cd6ed67f853cb6f910529b312)**

Comment: This suggestion is a good start but doesn't always work. It rejects all data at the extremities of full range. Unfortunately it rejects records equally at both ends of range. Although it correctly rejects the data for the stupidly tall person, it also rejects a proportion of the good data. The standard deviation function gives a number proportional to the spread of the data, it doesn't give any clues as to whereabouts in the range the most data is clustered.